# $f$ is concave and convex in its arguments.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that X be a reflexive Banach space and function $f:X×X↦R$ which is concave in its first argument and convex in its second one.
How to prove $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x∈X$?

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=-2x^2+y^2$ on $X=\mathbb R$?

Comment: What about $f(x,x) = 1$?